# prevent Custom ListView Refreshing on scroll. I want to stop refreshing

Tags: android, android-edittext, page-refresh, custom-lists, onscroll

I am using Custom ListView in My Android App. The Problem is when i am scrolling ListView, it automatically clears entered data from EditText( Edittext as a list_item ) and it ListView refreshed. I Want to Prevent it to stop clearing entered data on ListView Scroll.
Please Help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) define custom list adapter

2) define a an object for each item like `class MyClass { String myText}`

3) store the value of the EditText of each item in that object

I have a code for storing the state of CheckBox. use and customize it for EditText.

```
protected interface MyTextWatcher extends TextWatcher {

    public void setEnabled(EditText editText, boolean enable);

    public void setText(EditText editText, String text);
}

private MyTextWatcher generalTextWatcher = new MyTextWatcher() {

        private boolean enabled_edtQty = true;
        private boolean enabled_edtPackingQty = true;

        public void setEnabled(EditText editText, boolean enable) {
            if (editText.equals(edtQty))
            {
                this.enabled_edtQty = enable;
            }
            else if (editText.equals(edtPackingQty))
            {
                this.enabled_edtPackingQty = enable;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if (this.enabled_edtQty && edtQty != null
                    && edtQty.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
            {
                edtQty_onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
            }
            else if (this.enabled_edtPackingQty && edtPackingQty != null
                    && edtPackingQty.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
            {
                edtPackingQty_onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void setText(EditText editText, String text) {

            this.setEnabled(editText, false);

            editText.setText(text);

            this.setEnabled(editText, true);
        }

    };


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View rowView;
            final MyClass item = getItem(position);

             edtQty.addTextChangedListener(generalTextWatcher);
             edtPackingQty.addTextChangedListener(generalTextWatcher);

             generalTextWatcher.setText(edtQty, item.myText1);
             generalTextWatcher.setText(edtPackingQty, item.myText2);


    }


    protected void edtQty_onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
                              item.myText1 = s;
            }

    protected void edtPackingQty_onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
                              item.myText2 = s;
            }
```

in your situation you should use `addTextChangedListener` instead of `setOnCheckedChangeListener`

Comment: I have two EditText control in one list item, so when i get more records, then how can i maintain values runtime?

Comment: Thanx For Help. but i have bit confusion. can you please tell me what is "EntAcc002"?

Comment: @Android_User it is an example of a class. I changed it.

Comment: hmmm.. but i can't understand which class i need to put over there?

Comment: its only a last bug in my demo app. Please Help me :(

Comment: @Android_User a class that stores itams' data. for example if you show 3 values in each item of list, your class must have 3 fields.

Comment: i created one POJO file with two String variables and Getter-Setter. but i am getting error in final **MyClass item = getItem(position);** and **protected void edtQty_onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count)
    {
     item.myText1 = s;
 }

    protected void edtPackingQty_onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count)
    {
     item.myText2 = s;
    }**

Comment: @Android_User you should lean how to create a custom adapter. look at these examples: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/   and http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: ok friend. thanx for help but i am already using custom adapter. but only confusion with **getItem(position)**.

Comment: you should define a custom adapter like this: `public class AdapterGroupingSplySupplier extends
  ArrayAdapter<MyClass> {

 private Typeface tf;
 private int rsc;

 public AdapterGroupingSplySupplier(Context context, int resource,
   MyClassCollection items) {
  super(context, resource, items);
  tf = Farsi.GetFarsiFont((Activity) context);
  rsc = resource;
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

the answer by breceivemail is correct,

you can also try using ArrayList for storing data
onTextChangeListener can store data when needed
and you can restore data in getView of your listview's adapter

Note: if you are searching for stopping the listview from refreshing on scrolling, then you are going in wrong direction, because we can't stop listview from refreshing its contents(because all off screen contents are dumped in listviews), adapters are made to store/provide data when needed by listview(you can't rely on system to protect/store data you should store/restore data manually).