# Lost some items in listview when scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a listview with 1 checkbox and 2 buttons, I set checkbox VISIBLE and both buttons GONE. In main class, I have 1 method that to turn on/off show 2 button VISIBLE/GONE again, work perfect but when I am scrolling the listview some rows of listview lost 2 button again.

This is [my source code here](http://jumpshare.com/v/qILtLN?b=T7C9Fp)

Comment: You'll get much better & faster responses if you copy/paste the relevant code into your question body.

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14169969/779408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an array or list to save button/checkbox state, and also handle VISIBLE/GONE in the adapter's getView() method according to saved button/checkbox state. Because when you scroll, the cell content might be reconstructed by getView().

Comment: @BảoTrần If your problem got resolved, please upvote (by clicking the up arrow) and accept (by clicking the correct sign) my answer. So that I can get reputation from answering questions.